# query in sharepoint 2013 search

Tags: search-results

I have an issue in my portal.
In the default search box, when an item is searched using the enter button or by clicking the Search box, the post back happens and the URL is like below where 'sales' is the keyword I entered in the search box.

```
http://contoso.com/search/pages/results.aspx?k=sales
```

In the same page, if I type a new search item and when I select it from the query suggestions, the URL is like below where the new search keyword gets appended in the URL.

```
http://contoso.com/search/pages/results.aspx?k=sales#k=helpdesk
```

The newly selected search string gets appended in the back of the previously searched string. Because of this, when I move to a new search page the old results for the word 'sales' is getting displayed.

Is there any setting to change this for search items selected from query suggestions to post back or how to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off MDS. The minimum download strategy makes the pages load faster but it also messes with the URLs. I am curious why this is an issue for you.

Comment: I have many search pages based on languages. So when i select a keyword from dropdown and when i move to the next search page i am getting the results for the old search keyword and not for the latest one which i selected from query suggestions. Thats why,

Comment: Hmm, are these the out of the box web parts? They should not work that way, they should preserve the correct query term.